# Trim text and add timestamp?

Tags: bash

So basically I have my output as the following:

```
<span id="PlayerCount">134,015 people currently online</span>
```

What I want is a way to trim it to show:

```
134,015 - 3:24:20AM - Oct 24
```

Can anyone help? Also note the number may change so is it possible output everything between ">" and the "c" in currently? And add a timestamp somehow?

Using commands from terminal in Linux, so that's called bash right?

Comment: Are we talking about a bash script here?

Comment: bash script yes, I extracted that bit of html data and I want to trim it.

Comment: What language?  You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: @Inuyasha: the language is __bash__, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you perhaps mean something like:

```
$ echo '<span id="PlayerCount">134,015 people currently online</span>' | sed
    -e 's/^[^>]*>//'
    -e "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/"
```

which generates:

```
134,015 people 03:36:30 PM Oct 24 2011
```

The `echo` is just for the test data. The first `sed` command will change everything up to the first `>` character into nothing (ie, delete it).

The second one will change everything from the `currently` to the end of the line with the current date in your desired format (although I have added the year since I'm a bit of a stickler for detail).

The relevant arguments for `date` here are:

```
%r     locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., 11:11:04 PM)
%b     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
%d     day of month (e.g., 01)
%Y     year
```

A full list of format specifiers can be obtained from the `date` man page (execute `man date` from a shell).

---

A small script which will give you the desired information from the page you mentioned in the comments is:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
    | grep PlayerCount \
    | head -1l \
    | sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
    | sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/"
```

Running this gives me:

```
pax$ ./online.sh
132,682 people 04:09:17 PM Oct 24 2011
```

In detail:

- The `wget` bit pulls down the web page and writes it on standard output. The standard error (progress bar) is thrown away.
- The `grep` extracts only lines with the word `PlayerCount` in them.
- The `head` throws away all but the first of those.
- The first `sed` strips up to the first `>` character.
- The second `sed` changes the trailing text to the durrent date and time.

Comment: Yes! Is it possible to change the timestamp around like how I want it?

Comment: @Aaron, I've changed the format string to approximate what you want. As bos points out, all the possibilities are enumerated in the `date` man page.

Comment: The bit of text I got when I did a "wget" on a website and downloaded it. Is it possible to just look at the site for that amount of people currently online without downloading anything? Big questions I know, sorry.

Comment: @Aaron, `wget` on the single downloadable "file" then using `grep` to get the specific line, then `sed` to massage it into your desired format is probably the easiest way to do it, unless the internet site itself provides an easier way, like `http://example.com/just_get_users_online_as_plan_text`.

Comment: @paxdiablo do you think you could help me with the wget part? All I want is to display what you helped me with, but I feel it could be done easier.. http://runescape.com/title.ws is the site, and under that, you will see where it says the amount of players online. All I want is to get that number with a timestamp :3

Comment: @Aaron, that probably should be a separate question but I've added a little script at the end of my answer that does what you want.

Comment: Wow perfect :3 Thanks. Okay one last question! What should I add at the end to make it rerun by itself every...10mintes?

Comment: @Aaron. Don't change the script. Just put in in as a cron job that runs every ten minutes, and append the output to `/tmp/online.txt` to keep a history. Don't ask me about cron here in the comments, there are bucketloads of questions already on SO that will tell you how to use it :-)

Comment: I have to change the online.tmp in the script to online.txt? And that will make a text file showing all the outputs?

Comment: The script will be as it currently is (following my last edit). The cron entry will be somthing like `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /full/path/to/that/script >>/tmp/online.txt` (every 10 minutes, appending output to `/tmp/online.txt`). Then all the historical info can be obtained from that file.

Answer (score 1):

Quickhack(tm):

```
$ people=$(echo '<span id="PlayerCount">134,015 people currently online</span>' | \
           sed -e 's/^.*>\(.*\) people.*$/\1/')
$ echo $people - $(date)
134,015 - Mon Oct 24 09:36:23 CEST 2011
```

Comment: Thanks! :O I like that one also.

Answer (score 1):

```
produce_OUTPUT | grep -o '[0-9,]\+' | while read count; do 
  printf "%s - %s\n" $count "$(date +'%l:%M:%S %p - %b %e')"
done
```